# Eclipse show java error when I change drive where is storage

Tags: java, eclipse

I've changed the eclipse folder from d: to f: and when I start is showing a Java popup error "Could not create the Java Virtual Machine"

Comment: Reinstall eclipse to `F`. That's the easiest way IMO

Answer (score 0):

As long as your JDK location has not changed , this error should not come up. Can you try starting eclipse with the -vm option

eclipse -vm /bin/javaw and see if it starts up ?

Comment: eclipse.ini --launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-vmargs
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-vm
E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: can you enclose in double quotes "E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\bin\javaw.exe"